# PHP $_POST into array and output array

Tags: php, forms, post, foreach

I have been trying to create a php script which takes any number from a text form, and puts it into an array. Then I want to loop through the array and output each number.

So far with some searching around on Google, I've come up with this piece of code. Unfortunatly it doesn't work. The strange thing is, I actually got it working at some point, but somehow the code wouldn't function anymore without actually changing anything in the script.

Can anyone help me complete this, I have my version which worked at some point but doesn't anymore.

(I know I should filter input but since this is just an exercise it doesn't really matter.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>13.13</title>

<body>
    <h2> Inputting numbers into array through form</h2>
    <br>
    <br>

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="number" />
        <input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>

<?php
    session_start();    

        if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
            $number = $_REQUEST['number'];

            if (!isSet($_SESSION['number'])) {
                $_SESSION['number'] = array();
            }
        array_push($_SESSION['number'], $number);

        foreach($_SESSION['number'] as $key => $val) {
            echo $key . ">" . $val;
        }
    }

?>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post sample input and sample output ?

Comment: It does not show anything at all when I submit the form.

Comment: `<input type="submit"`

Comment: `<form method="post">`

Comment: That was the problem... Can't believe I've missed that!

Comment: you need to put `session_start()` at the very head of your page before any further output happens.. or it will not work.  You probalby aren't seeing this because you're suppressing error mode.

Comment: It works perfectly without method="post" by the way.

Comment: Putting method="post" won't make a difference - the _REQUEST object is going to pull a _GET just as well

Answer (score 1):

Move `session_start()` to the top of your code before any HTML output.  You can't start a session after headers have already been sent - and they have been sent because HTML output has been sent.

It's just good practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `method` in your form.

Here' the full code, also, always place `session_start` at the top of the page.

```
<?php
    session_start();    

        if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
            $number = $_REQUEST['number'];

            if (!isSet($_SESSION['number'])) {
                $_SESSION['number'] = array();
            }
        array_push($_SESSION['number'], $number);

       /* foreach($_SESSION['number'] as $key => $val) {
            echo $key . ">" . $val;
        }
        */
        var_dump($_SESSION['number']);
    }

?>    

<html>
<head>
    <title>13.13</title>

<body>
    <h2> Inputting numbers into array through form</h2>
    <br>
    <br>

    <form method="post" action="#">
        <input type="text" name="number" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>



</body>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: FWIW, it was explained in the comments that `method="post"` was not needed as apparently forms default to `method="get"`. That can be read from `$_REQUEST`.